# Why is the ball not dead on a fake field goal in college football?

Tags: rules, american-football, collegiate

How can there be a fake field goal or extra point in college when the holder starts out with his knee on the ground? This should instantly ground the ball if the kicker isn't going to kick it.

Answer (score 7):

The rules make a special exception for the case of a kick holder, or else place kicks would be nearly impossible to execute.

In NCAA Rule 4, section 1:

> ARTICLE 3. A live ball becomes dead and an official shall sound his whistle
>   or declare it dead:
>   [...]
>   b. When any part of the ball carrier’s body, except his hand or foot, touches the ground or when the ball carrier is tackled or otherwise falls and loses possession of the ball as he contacts the ground with any part of his body, except his hand or foot **[Exception: The ball remains alive when an offensive player has simulated a kick or at the snap is in position to kick the ball held for a place kick by a teammate. The ball may be kicked, passed or
>   advanced by rule]**

Answer (score 3):

You are only down if you *possess the football* and are on a knee.

Take a look at [this fake extra point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cILlBazwV8) Oregon executed for a 2 point conversion in the 2011 BCS championship game. Note how the holder comes out of his crouch and *does not* have his knee touching the ground when he receives the football.

Additionally, there is a specific excpetion for the holder on a scrimmage kick

[Rule 4, section 1, article 3, b](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/FR14.pdf)

> Exception: The ball remains alive when an offensive player has simulated a kick or at the snap is in position to kick the ball held for a place kick by a teammate. The ball may be kicked, passed or advanced by rule.

Comment: That's true, but that's not the reason it's legal. Some fakes have the holder, still one one knee, tossing the ball backwards over his head to the kicker. And besides, the holder possesses the ball with his knee down on *every single kick*.

Comment: I'll have to investigate. It's likely there is a special rule, since a holder is not down when he's holding (which under normal circumstances he would be)

Comment: I just went to utube and the first fake FG they showed was with the holder on his knee through his part in the play, again the question remains.